# how to show pagination and search and button in datatables

Tags: pagination, datatables

Im using datatables, and the problem is can't combine pagination, buttons and search in the same time,now I can combine pagination and buttons but need also search to be with them! here code

```
    var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'lBrtip',
           buttons: [

        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
         ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `f` to your dom to display search on your table. Just put it based on where you want the search field to be positioned.

Eg:

```
var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        dom: 'flBrtip',
       buttons: [

    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    'pdfHtml5'
     ],
```

Check the dom documentation here:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom